# Classes that implement an interface have more methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an interface:

```
public interface IUser {
   public boolean login();
}
```

and two classes that implement this interface:

```
public class UserA implements IUser{

   public boolean login() {
       System.out.println("login");
   }

  public void update() {
      System.out.println("update");
  }
}


public class UserB implements IUser {

   public boolean login() {
       System.out.println("login");
   }

   public void delete() {
       System.out.println("delete");
   }
}
```

My question is if I create a user:

```
IUser user = new UserA();
```

*user* object doesn't have access to *update()* however it is recommended to create object using interface, I was wondering if there is a best practice or design pattern I can use (rather than casting it)?

Comment: May I ask the reason for not using casting ?

Comment: "Why not casting": Because it can fail. *Unless* the caller exactly knows the type. And **if** he knows (and has to know) the type, why does he receive the interface at all? The (broad) questions here are *who* has to create the instances, *who* has to know the instances under *which* type, and *what* does he do with these instances...

Comment: Yes that could happen , but in the question OP mentions `if I create a user...` , so I would assume the Op is the user, and is aware of his types :)

Comment: A less neat solution but also worth mentioning could be an `Adapter`. Otherwise there is also the possibility of an abstract base class with empty implementations for `update` and `delete`. However safe casting with `if instanceof...` might be easiest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good practice to "code to the interface".

However, that only works if that interface has all the methods you need.

If not, you need to either use the concrete class instead of the interface (which is not necessarily bad, it depends on the situation), or rethink how your interfaces are designed.

Comment: Please provide insight, as I am not an expert, `is casting considered as bad practice` ? I use it without guilt if required, because however carefully we design there can be cases when interfaces/superclasses may not include all methods and Ref variables have to be casted to access those methods.

Comment: In your concrete example, the interface (or a sub-interface, or an unrelated interface) could have `update` and `delete` methods. Rule of thumb: If you have more than one class, and people other than the ones who created the instance should call methods on them, you probably want an interface.

Comment: @Mustafasabir: yes, casting is a sign of a design problem. If a method takes a IUser as argument, but will fail with a ClassCastException every time the IUser is not a UserA, then the method should take a UserA as argument.

Answer (score 2):

It's a best practice to program on interface when the code only needs the interface type to work. If the code needs an object of type `UserA` to work, then you should declare your variable as UserA:

```
UserA user = new UserA();

...

// this methods does something applicable to all kinds of IUser
public void doSomething(IUser user) {
    ...
}

// this methods does something applicable only to UserA
public void doSomethingElse(UserA user) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you need to use the `update` method, then change

```
    IUser user = new UserA();
```

to:

```
    UserA user = new UserA();
```

The *"code to the interface"* advice does not apply if your application *needs* to use methods that are only provided by the classes.

If you need to declare the variable's type as `IUser` for other reasons (e.g. for polymorphism) then a type cast is the only real option.  But beware that your code will need to deal with the case where the `IUser` is NOT `UserA`.

---

Actually, there is another approach.  You could add `update` and `delete` to `IUser`, and in the cases where they don't make sense, implement them as:

```
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
```

However, that is just replacing one problem (type cast exceptions) with another (unsupported operation exceptions) ... with the additional downside that there is nothing at the point where you need to make the call to indicate syntactically that that there is a potential problem.

---

If you are interested in "better ways" to do this, take a look at the way that Ceylon avoids the problem of type cast exceptions by using a form of `switch` statement to switch on an object's type.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context of your code. If your variable `user` always points to a `UserA` object and you need those operations, I think it's okay to declare the variable as `UserA`. If that's not the case, I would refactor to ensure that in the scope of the variable only one of the concrete types are used (similar to what JB wrote in his answer).

Additionally you could introduce two more interfaces `UpdatableUser` and `DeleteableUser` that extend `IUser`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should 'Code to Interface'. But you can use following statement withon your method:

```
UserA user = new UserA();
```

and you have the full functionality of the `UserA` class. Use it as **long as you are working with your** method(s). As soon as your method ends or you call another method only pass the `IUser` around not the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rethink if the method update() and delete() is the method other object should use.

if they will not use by others,  update() and delete() should be private method. So you should no modify IUser.

If update() and delete() will be invoked in other, you can create two interface updatable and deletable. Then in the place you want to invoke, you should cast the IUser to interface updatable or deletable.